# alternate phrase for "signing acceptance" in an agreement?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need alternate words for "signing your acceptance" in an agreement.

Comment: Can you give a full sentence, for context?

Comment: Signing a contract means to accept its terms. That is the very purpose and definition of *to sign* a contract. You doubt need an additional adjective or another word to convey this meaning. Having said that, an alternative word is *execute* [the contract].

Answer (score 1):

**Ratify**

Sign or give formal consent to (a treaty, contract, or agreement), making it officially valid.
*New American Dictionary 2007*

As distinct from *approve, sanction, endorse,* etc, *ratify* means signing the agreement or contract.

- Fred finally ratified the agreement with Sally.
- "Sally, could you please let me know if the employment agreement has been ratified or not."

Separetely, we do not normally say *sign your acceptance*, because it is redundant.  In the context of a contract (or anything that requires a signature) *sign* means *accept*.

Comment: I am pretty sure that "ratify" is only used where you have somebody other than the contracting parties who have the power to invalidate the agreement. It's usually the legislature. You know, the Senate and its thing about not ratifying international treaties. Possibly the CEO or Chairman in a commercial setting. Fred and Sally make an agreement, who is doing the ratifying? I think that's an error. And for OP, I would note that Brits talk about "closing" an agreement, especially in the house sales business.

Comment: @David Pugh. (a) No.  Check a dictionary.  The ratifier is the signer. (b) Closing a deal or a sale is quite a different thing: there is a duration between signature and conveyance, during which the deal may not "close". (c) Fell free to submit an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "**to sign**" and "**to ratify**" may signify two different actions in law:

> [Wills, Trusts, and Estates Administration](https://books.google.ca/books?id=zx6gAfZWvg0C&pg=PA57&dq=%22ratified%20the%20agreement%20%22%20divorce&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G5k_Vc2hM6bmsASmroCICg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ratified%20the%20agreement%20%22%20divorce&f=false) - Page 57 Dennis R. Hower, ‎Peter Kahn - 2011
>
> In most community property states, even without divorce, spouses may
>   at any time enter into an agreement that ... only by the husband
>   against his interest in the community property since the wife had
>   **neither signed nor ratified the agreement**.

Now, "ratify" is generally really higher level, where states and parliaments are concerned, not husbands and wives:-). But the latter is out there:

> [Corpus Juris Secundum: A Complete Restatement of the ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=UPUnAQAAMAAJ&q=%22wife%20ratified%20the%20agreement%20%22%20divorce&dq=%22wife%20ratified%20the%20agreement%20%22%20divorce&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZZk_VcHEAebIsQSprYCwDQ&redir_esc=y) 2005
>
> Divorce ... the former wife **ratified the agreement entered on her
>   behalf by her acceptance of the agreement's benefits**

and the lawyers are using it, but look at the comparative stats at Google Books:

["**wife** ratified the agreement"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ratified%20the%20agreement%20%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22wife%20ratified%20the%20agreement%20%22)
About 63 results

["**parliament** ratified the agreement"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ratified%20the%20agreement%20%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22parliament%20ratified%20the%20agreement%22)
About 2,160 results

Comment: I thought the point of this site was to determine the correct usage of words, not the common (and ever-changing) usage of the uneducated masses.  Any dictionary informs us that *ratify* and *sign* mean the same thing; the definition of *ratify* uses the word *sign* and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

*Tu quoque*. Unfortunately I no longer have my full dead-trees version of the OED. Merriam-Webster supports me not you.The ratifier makes a signed agreement official. Logically has to be a third party.

Comment: This would appear to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: True, dat. Apologies. It was meant to be a reply to Performance, whose tone annoyed me. I thought I _had_ posted it in comments and was honestly surprised to see where it was.

Comment: (a) You get tone out of words of explanation on a page ??? Pardon me, but I swear I didn't put any tone into my words.  (b) What third party ? You are introducing complications, that has the effect of confusing the initial problem: what ratify means.  if that is not your intent, I suggest you change your comment/answer.